# How does one parse entire contents of a text file that have been read into a list, to a class?

Tags: python

```
from itertools import islice
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, social, firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth, State):
        self.social = social
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth
        self.State = State
    def tenPeople(self):
        for i in range(10):
            #print(self.social)
            print('{}  {}  {}  {}  {}'.format(self.social, self.firstName, self.lastName,self.dateOfBirth,     self.State))
            break
count = 0
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        person = f.readline()
        person = person.split()
         #parse the split contents of file to class Person
        person = Person(person[0], person[1], person[2], person[3], person[4])

        person.tenPeople()
        count+=1
print(count)
```

My my file has a 1000 lines of text, however, count only shows that the for-loop iterated 500 times. When I print count, it shows 500. How do I get all the lines in the text file to be counted. Also, how can I make def tenPeople(self) print only 10 lines, not the 500 lines in the file.

Comment: `for line in f` that iterates over the lines of the file, when you then do `person = f.readline()` you are skipping the line already read into `line`. meaning you are skipping every second line.